# How to find modified files in a component using cleartool?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

we have created a component in UCM. Many files were changed since but few files were not at all changed after version 1.

We can find the list of files using createdsince. but in this case we need to specify the date. Is there any way to find the list of files which are modified since creation.

In other words find list of files which has version greater than 1 in version tree.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare current versions with the `stream/1` versions, and that isn't always the initial baseline of a component.
Actually, if you didn't imported an initial non-UCM label as a baseline, then the initial baseline is empty (no version in it).

The trick is, when using the [query language](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm), you cannot use [version selector](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm) *and* a query

So, what you can do is apply a label to all `version 1`, and then look for all elements which have at least one version without that label (see [find examples](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)).

```
cleartool find . –version 'version(.../streamName/1)' –exec "cleartool mklabel V1 \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\"" 
cleartool find . -version '{!lbtype(REL1)}'
```